# Android cmake different abi

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

Im using prebuilt android native library: `libcrypto.a`.
Library is compiled for `armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86`.
Structure:

```
-app
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - libs
    - armeabi
    - armeabi-v7a
    - x86
```

Each folder (`armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86`) contains folders `lib`(contains `libcrypto.a`) and `include` (contains header files).
CMake code:

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library(crypto STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(crypto
  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       crypto
                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib})
```

In my own `native-lib` i wanna use `libcrypto.a`. But when i wanna import header file f.e. `#include "openssl/md5.h"` android studio does not see that file.
And offer me to include one of THREE files from different abis:

```
"../../../libs/x86/include/openssl/md5.h"
"../../../libs/armeabi/include/openssl/md5.h"
"../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/include/openssl/md5.h"
```

Is there any way to create one version of my library (`native-lib`), include only 1 header and let android studio to choose abi automatically?

Smth like:

```
#include "openssl/md5.h"
```

but in the same time use 3 abi version.
Or i should use prebuilt included libraries not like that?

**#EDIT1**

```
target_include_directories(crypto INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)
```

Not working, getting CMake error.

Before that i have used

```
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an include directory so that the compiler can find `openssl/md5.h`.

The most idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
target_include_directories(crypto INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)
```

Unfortunately, CMake is silly, and doesn't actually let you do this yet on imported library targets, so you have to set the property manually, like so:

```
set_target_properties(crypto
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include
)
```

That adds that include directory to the interface of crypto, which means it also gets used when building native-lib, as properties which are preceded with INTERFACE are propagated to the users of that target. Using INTERFACE properties is the natural way in CMake to propagate usage requirements to consumers of a library.

Comment: Oops, yep, fixed it. Sorry about that; I assumed Cmake would be slight more sensible than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to one of the codes below:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include")
```

Or

```
target_include_directories(native-lib "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include")
```

If I'm not wrong, `target_include_directories` include files to a specific target. Since you are importing the header file in your `native-lib` files, `target_include_directories` must aim the `native-lib`.. and not `crypto`.. Those header files are not necessary to `crypto`... but to `native-lib`.

For any case, you can set `include_directories` which will add those header files to all targets (`native-lib` and `crypto`).

Also, remember:

1 - Edit your CMakeLists.txt

2 - Perform a project sync

3 - Only after that, open your `native-lib.cpp` file and try to import the file header file again.